# Check checkboxes with another checkbox has been checked

Tags: javascript, razor

I want my checkboxes to be checked when the below if check is true.. inside that check box I am using Javascript code to check it. Using mvc

```
@if (str_item != "" && str_checkroles != "" && str_item == str_checkroles) {

<script>
    src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js" >
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#@(item.Text)').attr('checked', true);

            $('#dummychk').prop('checked', true);
        });
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What you want is not very clear. For now, You're just checking some checkboxes. In your if, what are str_item and str_checkroles?

Comment: these are some string values..
i added if(...) here because i want to tell you that whenever the condition is true it should run the script.. but it is not happening

Comment: Okay, I'd have guessed it myself since it begins with 'str', thanks, but be clear on what you ask.

Comment: i want this script to get the id of these checkboxes.. and check them whenever the conditon is true

Answer (score 0):

'item.Text' - is the id of text box?

Please use (below answer i posted based on 'item.Text' this as id of check box)

$('#item.Text').attr('checked', true);

Instead of this..

$('#@(item.Text)').attr('checked', true);

But i willing to help you..Please share id of both check boxes which used in html element in view.

Comment: yeah it is the id of checkbox.. i have generated checkboxes dynamically

Comment: item.text is populated with the help of viewbag.. and my checkboxes are also populated by viewbag.. thats why i am using item.Text as the id..

Comment: $('#item.Text').attr('checked', true);  its not work for you..Actually your problem is script not running in if condition or script shows error? Like "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized

Comment: there is no error..even not in the browser's console.. 
this script or you can say the jquery is not running

Comment: Please share the view bag code which you passed and how you used in view.

Comment: ViewBag.Checkroles = new SelectList(context.UserRoles.Where(x => x.Userid == uid).Select(x => x.Roleid).ToList());

Comment: foreach (var item in Roles)
                {
                    if (checkroles != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var itemcheck in checkroles)
                        {
                            if (item.Value == itemcheck.Text)
                            {
                                str_checkroles = itemcheck.Text;
                                str_item = item.Value;
                         }

                        }
                    }

Comment: <input id="@item.Text" type="checkbox" value="@item.Value"  name="roles" />@item.Text<br />
                        <input id="dummychk" type="checkbox" value="@item.Value" name="roles" /> <br />

Comment: You can check the id of check box which one you click under html in inspect element. Then you can use this check box id in script $('#Id').attr('checked', true);

Comment: dear, i am generating checkboxes form viewbag so i cant check their id's..
and basically the id is the value of the selectlist. i dont want to hardcode it in the jquery...

Comment: Ok dear, pls try this.. you can use class name as "children" in input element. using this class you can get  class name when you click the check box using click event .. in which you can get id of check box using $(this).attr('id')..then you can use this id in your script as..$('#id).attr('checked', true);